# Bluestack's software wrecked my computer's virtulization and docker desktop

Tags: virtualization, docker, bluestacks

I am running windows 10 home. I installed docker wsl2 backed on my system and later on tried installing Bluestacks. Bluestacks made me download this .exe file that was supposed to turn off HyperV (I realized later that windows 10 home does not support HyperV). Now I'm getting this error every time I try to open Docker Desktop.

[image: error]

So far I have checked the bios, I have installed wsl2, upgraded the kernel package.

This is the bluestacks software

I'm not able to share any photos so I have pasted the preview in google docs for more understandability.

Comment: Windows 10 Home also contains HyperV as it is used for WSL2

Comment: Yes Robert but how do get my docker desktop up and running?

Comment: What do you mean you have installed Docker in WSL2? Anyway, if System Restore is enabled, you may be able to rollback the system to before you executed this `.exe`.

Comment: Simply search for "Windows 10 Hyperv enable" and you end up here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35812945/150978

Comment: Hey robert, I already tried using powershell commands and it didn't work. I got the fix just now anyway.

[I found it here](https://www.itechtics.com/enable-hyper-v-windows-10-home/)

Comment: @NagaKarumuri if that solution helped you, consider posting it as an answer to your question to make it easier to find for others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your virtualization settings have been modified due to Bluestacks HyperV remover tool on windows 10 home, I suggest you follow this https://www.itechtics.com/enable-hyper-v-windows-10-home/

There is a HyperV installer tool in the link and PowerShell command to enable hyper V.